# Precache Method image does not cache

Tags: flutter

Sorry for my poor English. I implemented the prechace of the assets but he does not hear any changes, always the first time that I select an icon of the guide he has a small delay of change of state, after the navigation is smooth with quick change of state of the icons, I am beginner in flutter, perhaps Do something wrong with my logic. Could someone with a little more experience see where I am wrong? I'm using a physical device for testing, android.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:gestorgendo/pages/Dash/ScheduleScreen.dart';

class DashScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _DashScreenState createState() => _DashScreenState();
}

class _DashScreenState extends State<DashScreen> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  TabController _tabcontroller;
  int _tabIndex = 0;
  Image calendarSelect;
  Image calendarUnselect;
  Image invoiceSelect;
  Image invoiceUnselect;
  Image addSelect;
  Image addUnselect;
  Image chatSelect;
  Image chatUnselect;
  Image settingsSelect;
  Image settingsUnselect;

  List<Widget> _tabListBody = [ new ScheduleScreen(), new ScheduleScreen(), new ScheduleScreen(), new ScheduleScreen(), new ScheduleScreen()];
  @override
  void initState(){
    super.initState();
      calendarSelect = new Image.asset("assets/icons/calendar_2.png",width: 26.0, height: 26.0);
      calendarUnselect = new Image.asset("assets/icons/calendar_grey_2.png",width: 26.0, height: 26.0);

      invoiceSelect = new Image.asset("assets/icons/invoice.png",width: 30.0, height: 30.0);
      invoiceUnselect = new Image.asset("assets/icons/invoice_grey.png",width: 30.0, height: 30.0);

      addSelect = new Image.asset("assets/icons/add.png",width: 26.0, height: 26.0);
      addUnselect = new Image.asset("assets/icons/add_grey.png",width: 26.0, height: 26.0);

      chatSelect = new Image.asset("assets/icons/chat.png",width: 26.0, height: 26.0);
      chatUnselect = new Image.asset("assets/icons/chat_grey.png",width: 26.0, height: 26.0);

      settingsSelect = new Image.asset("assets/icons/settings.png",width: 26.0, height: 26.0);
      settingsUnselect = new Image.asset("assets/icons/settings_grey.png",width: 26.0, height: 26.0);

    _tabcontroller = new TabController(length: 5, vsync: this);
    _tabcontroller.addListener((){
      setState(() {
        _tabIndex = _tabcontroller.index;
      });
    });
  }
    @override
    void didChangeDependencies() async {
      super.didChangeDependencies();
      await precacheImage(calendarSelect.image,context);
      await precacheImage(calendarUnselect.image,context);

      await precacheImage(invoiceSelect.image,context);
      await precacheImage(invoiceUnselect.image,context);

      await precacheImage(addSelect.image,context);
      await precacheImage(addUnselect.image,context);

      await precacheImage(chatSelect.image,context);
      await precacheImage(chatUnselect.image,context);

      await precacheImage(settingsSelect.image,context);
      await precacheImage(settingsUnselect.image,context);

    }
  @override
  void dispose() {
    // Dispose of the Tab Controller
    _tabcontroller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      body: new TabBarView(
        controller: _tabcontroller,
        children: _tabListBody,
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: new TabBar(
        controller: _tabcontroller,
        tabs: <Widget>[
          Tab(
            //icon: new Icon(Icons.calendar_today, color: _tabIndex == 0 ? Colors.green : Colors.grey),
            icon: _tabIndex == 0 
                  ? calendarSelect
                  : calendarUnselect
            //text:"Home",      
          ),
          Tab(
            //icon: new Icon(Icons.search, color: _tabIndex == 1 ? Colors.green : Colors.grey),
            icon: _tabIndex == 1 
                  ? invoiceSelect
                  : invoiceUnselect
            //text: "Busca"
          ),
          Tab(
            //icon: new Icon(Icons.add_box, color: _tabIndex == 2 ? Colors.green : Colors.grey),
            icon: _tabIndex == 2 
                  ? addSelect
                  : addUnselect
            //text: "Add"
          ),
          Tab(
            //icon: new Icon(Icons.message, color: _tabIndex == 3 ? Colors.green : Colors.grey),
            icon: _tabIndex == 3 
                  ? chatSelect
                  : chatUnselect
            //text: "Favotiros"
          ),
          Tab(
            //icon: new Icon(Icons.more_vert, color: _tabIndex == 4 ? Colors.green : Colors.grey),
            icon: _tabIndex == 4 
                  ? settingsSelect
                  : settingsUnselect
            //text: "More"
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This behaviour is "normal" on Flutter.

The `didChangeDependencies` method is called after `build` method. Therefore, the precaching occurs after the screen is rendered. Even more, the `ImageProvider` class already handles precache and that's why you see no difference. Also you cannot call the precaching before the build, because it requires a context which you don't have on `initState()`. And if you call it on the `build` method (yes, it will be called with every state update, but you could use a boolean to know if you did it once, but you shouldn't do that anyway), the prechaching will end after the build completes because it returns a `Future` and you cannot await on `build`.

It looks like you're using the images as icons, so I suggest you use the Material or Cupertino icons libraries. If that doesn't cover your needs you may take a look at the FontAwesome library.

[font_awesome_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/font_awesome_flutter)

Anyway, if you need more information on this topic, there's an open issue about this on the Flutter repository, where you can even find a hack (which involves loading the images as base64) [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/26127).

I hope this helps you!

Comment: A yes now I understand better is not very frustrating because I would like to use linear icons a little more personalized, I will look for an alternative to this. Thanks for the answer.